# In Messages for iOS, can I delete an individual photos from a conversation?

Tags: macos, ios, photos, messages, attachments

While Messages for macOS allows for the deletion of individual photos from a conversation, the photos are not deleted on other iMessage clients so they have to be deleted off of each client that was open at the time. This is a problem when my girlfriend decides to text me risqué photos over the weekend and I left Messages running on my work machine. I guess I have some careful deleting to do tomorrow!

Anyway, I am unable to find out how to delete a photo from a conversation on iOS Messages at all. Is it even possible? The only way to do it appears to be to delete the entire conversation which I do **not** want to do. Anyone have any clues?

Comment: I will note that even with my mixed bag of El Cap and Sierra hosts, all 3 MacOS iMessage clients synced the deleted files. It is only on iOS 10 that the photos do not get removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the conversation on your iOS device (assuming iOS10). In the top right corner you should see an information symbol ("i" in a circle). Click on it. Then scroll down to the picture you want to delete. Then tap and hold the picture. Three options will come up: copy, delete, more. Select delete. If you're using an iPhone 6s or newer, be careful not to force touch the image instead of tapping and holding.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was I was force touching the image which prevent the delete options from showing.

Answer (score 1):

iMessage operates like SMS or old-school email, not like webmail or FB messenger where what you're viewing is basically a real-time mirror of the server. Once a message has been delivered to your devices the server is done with it, so no, there are no take-backs of the way you're hoping for.

Basically, tell your girlfriend to send you sensitive stuff through another medium in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... and noted. I still am not sure when I am going to delete those things!

Comment: Just realized you basically stated as much haha, and didn't ask about that particular aspect, sorry.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a bigger issue, tbh. Everyone needs a 24/7 backdoor to their work machine(s), hey. Get on it!

Comment: I actually have JumpDesktop to it so I'm good. Thanks!

Comment: Odd, for whatever reason, pictures in the MacOS version of iMessage must allow for the photos to be deleted as they were not there!

Comment: Hmm, doesn't sound right. If you delete a message before it's been delivered to a particular device it won't ever be downloaded by it, but as far as I know that's the only way, it's not supposed to be 2-way after the fact. Maybe something new in 10.12/iOS10? Would be about damn time, to be honest...

Comment: It might be something with Sierra. That's would be odd because while I deleted the pictures from the a Sierra host, the photos automatically deleted from both my other Sierra machine at home as well as the El Cap machine at work. It was only the iOS 10 hosts that didn't delete those photos.